# WordPress AJAX Load Search Results for Posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load all posts that have the `video format` using `AJAX` but my request keeps dying and I cannot figure out why. I don't get any errors. I always get a `status 200`. I cannot for the life of me figure it out and I fell like it is probably something very small.

here is my form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="//localhost:3000/">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-group-field" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Start Your Search">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="video-gallery">
        <div class="input-group-button">
            <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
function ajaxVideoSearch(){
    $(document).on('click','#searchsubmit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form    = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $input   = $form.find('input[name="s"]');
    var query    = $input.val();
    var $content = $('.gallery-container');

        $.ajax({
            url: templateURL + '/page-templates/ajax-search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {query : query},
            beforeSend: function() {
        $content.addClass('loading');
      },
            success: function(response) {
        $content.html(response);
      }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the page with my query `ajax-search.php`

```
<?php if($_POST['query']) { ?>
<h1>Search Query: <?php echo $_POST['query']; ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
<div class="row medium-up-3">

    <!-- query video post format -->
    <?php
      $query  = $_POST['query'];

        $search = new WP_Query( array(
        's'         => $query,
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('post-format-video')
          )
        ),
        ));

      if($search->have_posts()) { while($search->have_posts()) { $search->the_post(); 
    ?>

    <div class="column column-block" title="Play Video" data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-video="<?php the_field('video_link'); ?>">
        <a href="#!"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <h5 class="video-title white-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
        <p class="video-body white-p"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php }

  }else{echo '<p>hello</p>';}

    ?>

</div>
```

This is what I get in my response. It appears to die after the third line. I get:

```
<h1>Search Query: clearplex</h1>
<div class="row medium-up-3">

    <!-- query video post format -->
```

Comment: Does seem to die right around where you have that single `e` standing on a line all by itself, yes ...

Comment: yeah, sorry, i removed that. That e is not actually there otherwise i would get a 500 error

Comment: Then enable proper PHP error reporting, so that you get told what the problem is.

Comment: i dont have any errors. I have error reporting on.

Comment: Can’t be. Then you would have to get at least the closing `</div>` to show in your output as well, because that is completely independent from the PHP logic. You don’t, ergo the only logical conclusion is - the script _died_ before that point, for some reason.

Comment: I have debug set to `true` in `wp-config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are using non WP file. in order to use WP functionality in no WP template hierarchy you need to include wordpress base file to use `WP_*` functions.

try adding both line in <kbd>**ajax-search.php**</kbd>

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php';
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

<kbd>**ajax-search.php**</kbd>

```
<?php 
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php';
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

if($_POST['query']) { ?>
<h1>Search Query: <?php echo $_POST['query']; ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```